# How can i fix .take() operator and preserve snapshot || Angular , Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire

I have a problem in `.take()` operator after they change to `AngulaFireObject` 
and `preserveSnapshot`.
What can be the problem?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile/profile.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operator/take';


@Injectable()

export class DataService {
  profileObject : AngularFireObject<Profile>
  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getProfile(user: User) {
    this.profileObject = this.database.object(`/profiles/${user.uid}`, { preserveSnapshot:  true }); <<<in here

    return this.profileObject.take(1); <<<< and here
  }

async  saveProfile(user: User, profile: Profile) {
this.profileObject = this.database.object(`/profiles/${user.uid}`);
```

When I run my app with `ionic serve` it gives me this

```
Typescript Error Expected 1 arguments, but got 2. C:/Users/A7MD/Desktop/WallPapa/src/providers/data/data.service.ts getProfile(user: User) { this.profileObject = this.database.object(/profiles/${user.uid}, { preserveSnapshot: true }); –
```

and

`Typescript Error Property 'take' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<Profile>'. C:/Users/A7MD/Desktop/WallPapa/src/providers/data/data.service.ts return this.profileObject.take(1); }`

You can see the photo here:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what's happening, or what you wish to achieve so that it's easier to assist you. As it is, it's unclear what the problem you're experiencing is.

Comment: Typescript Error
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
C:/Users/A7MD/Desktop/WallPapa/src/providers/data/data.service.ts
getProfile(user: User) {
  this.profileObject = this.database.object(`/profiles/${user.uid}`, { preserveSnapshot:  true });

Comment: and 

_____________
Typescript Error
Property 'take' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<Profile>'.
C:/Users/A7MD/Desktop/WallPapa/src/providers/data/data.service.ts
   return this.profileObject.take(1);
 }

Comment: @AhmedHallaq details like this belong in the question, not comments. You can [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: @jdv Thank you and done